# Magento 2.3.X: No such entity with customerId = 259340

Tags: magento2.3

I am getting following error on every page after login.

I am using the magento2.3.2.

```
main.CRITICAL: No such entity with customerId = 259340
```

Comment: Check in your admin customer grid. this number customer exists of not? Also you can check in database customer_entity table.

Comment: Customer is exist in admin as well entry is showing in DB. This error is showing for both customers (old customers as well for newel created customers)

Comment: Once do run reindex command.

Comment: I have run already many time but it didn't work.

Comment: same issue coming for me.. I checked in admin grid-present.As well present in customer_entity table.I run reindex. What the exact issue of this.Once i update 
UPDATE quote SET customer_is_guest = 0 WHERE customer_id != 0 AND customer_is_guest = 1
for some time it works charm..After same issue happen again.